# How can I make this class FULLY immutable?

Tags: java, immutability

```
public final class Test {

    private final Date date;

    public Test() {
        date = new Date();
    }

    public Test(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Test:[date=" + date.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: what makes you assume it isn't already?

Comment: The `Date` class is mutable, so you would have to not expose your `date` field in the getter.

Comment: Don't expose it, then you won't have that problem.

Comment: the date variable isn't mutable, though

Comment: @Stultuske The referenced Date object obviously is.

Comment: @Tom without knowing what Date class we're talking about, I'm not going to say for sure it is.

Answer (score 6):

Instances of your class can't be changed per se, but since `Date` is mutable (assuming it's [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)), the information inside them could be changed.

For instance:

```
myTest.getDate().setTime(0L);
```

If you want to guard against that, you need to copy the `Date` defensively.

```
public Test(Date d) {
    this.date = new Date(d.getTime());
}
public Date getDate() {
    return new Date(this.date.getTime());
}
```

That way nothing outside the class can have access to your `date` field to mutate it.

Alternatively, use an immutable date type such as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) or [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instead of a mutable one.

Comment: Even better, use the immutable java.time library.

Comment: @shmosel Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Return a clone of the date objects instead.

```
public final class Test {

  private final Date date;

  public Test() {
    date = new Date();
  }

  public Test(Date date) {
    this.date = (Date)date.clone();
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return (Date)date.clone();
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Test:[date=" + date.toString() + "]";
  }
}
```

If you have performance concerns regarding the creation of new objects, you can instead store time as a `long` instead of a `Date` object.